# Автоматическое заполнение таблицы

Tags: база-данных, c++builder, access

Доброго времени суток.

Господа, подскажите, впал в депрессию.

С++Builder6 and Access. Создал базу, 3 таблицы, связал, как мог.

Цель:
Верхний грид - записывается график работы театра.
Нижний грид - служит для отслеживания ЗП сотрудникам.

Задача 1: требуется в нижний грид записывать дату (например, 01.09.2014) и название_театра (смешарики) - и автоматически должно в колонку "Количество" записать количество выступлений в день, в колонку "Сумма" записать сумму итогов за 01.09.2014.

Задача 2: как автоматизировать высчитывание ЗП рабочим по формуле на скрине?

Заранее спасибо. Подскажите план, что за чем следует делать (я новичок). Прислушаюсь, буду пробовать кодить.

http://www.programmersforum.ru/attachment.php?attachmentid=69786&d=1409683507
http://www.programmersforum.ru/attachment.php?attachmentid=69787&d=1409683507
http://www.programmersforum.ru/attachment.php?attachmentid=69788&d=1409683507

**Обновление**

Да пожалуйста:
http://s020.radikal.ru/i705/1409/ba/69091d02f6f0.png
http://s018.radikal.ru/i507/1409/3e/0b9c6a9fcedb.png
http://s004.radikal.ru/i206/1409/74/b5b6f4781391.png

Comment: @DimiTRUE, расскажите о таблицах подробно, пожалуйста.

Comment: На первом скрине таблицы и поля.

Comment: @DimiTRUE, придется здесь повторить. У меня нет туда доступа. Или Вам не слишком нужно?